# How to return single.deferred in closure

Tags: closures, rx-swift, deferred

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the Single from the closure?
How can I get value from Alamofire.request?

```
 func loadImageName(url: URL) -> Single<String> {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let query = data else {
        return .error(Error.notFound)
    }

        ...

    return Single.deferred {
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
            if let error = $0.error {
                return Single<String>.error(error)
            }

            return Single<String>.just(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'll want `Single.create`.

This takes a block, which has a single argument. This argument is a function that you can call to pass a `SingleEvent`, i.e. either a `.success(Element)` (where `Element` is `String` in your case) or an `.error`.

The block must return a `Disposable`. You can construct a `Disposable` that will do additional work when it gets disposed. In the context of network requests, it makes sense to cancel the request.

```
func loadImageName(url: URL) -> Single<String> {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let query = data else {
        return .error(Error.notFound)
    }

    // ...

    Single.create { single in
        let request = Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
            if let error = $0.error {
                return single(.error(error))
            }

            return single(.success(result))
        }

        return Disposables.create { request.cancel() }
    }
}
```